# mouse_event click coordinates, seems I am lost in coordinate sets

Tags: c++, mfc

It seems I am having difficulties specifying mouse coordinates for a call to `mouse_event`. No matter how I setup the call I cannot seem to get the mouse to move properly, and when it does it only goes to the top left or bottom right corner. `pWnd` is a pointer to a control that I would like to hopefully at some point click on, I am currently trying to figureout the coordinate system.

Any ideas why I might be moving the mouse properly?

```
pWnd->GetWindowRect(&wndRect);

        POINT lpPoint = POINT();
        lpPoint.x = wndRect.left;
        lpPoint.y = wndRect.top;

        ScreenToClient(mainFrm->GetSafeHwnd(), &lpPoint);

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE , (DWORD)lpPoint.x, (DWORD)lpPoint.y, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coordinates used by `mouse_event` don't correspond to window pixels, they map to a range of 0 to 65535 on the primary monitor. To quote from the [`MOUSEINPUT` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> If `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` value is specified, `dx` and `dy` contain normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface; coordinate (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner. In a multimonitor system, the coordinates map to the primary monitor.

This means you need to convert from window coordinates to this special range.

```
DWORD dx = muldiv(x - rectPrimaryMonitor.left, 65535, rectPrimaryMonitor.Width());
DWORD dy = muldiv(y - rectPrimaryMonitor.top, 65535, rectPrimaryMonitor.Height());
```

You might be able to eliminate the `left` and `top` from the equation since I think the coordinates of the primary monitor are (0,0) by definition.

I have no idea how this is supposed to work if you're in a monitor above or to the left of the primary, since `DWORD` is unsigned.

Comment: So I need to get the size of the screen in pixels, then do my `wndRect.top/pixelHeightMax`*`65535` to get the proper coordinate for the Y? Ok makes sense, thank you Mark! Sorry again; I'll wait two days, start bounty and send some your way!

Comment: @BumSkeeter, I'd try this solution first to make sure it works. Also thanks for the thought, but I don't really need the bounty.